# IllegalStateException when returning from Activity in a Master Detail Template

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am using activities to enter data to a Master Detail template and what I wanted to achieve is refreshing the data each time I exit an activity and return result, but each time I do that and try to select 1 of the items in the template I get this illegal state exception.
The code below works if it's not called after closing an activity.

When I commit the support fragment manager I get this error, if I change commit to commitAllowingStateLoss the code continues, but it doesn't reload the detailed data.
Any help with this issue will be much appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(int id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(CategoryDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        CategoryDetailFragment fragment = new CategoryDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.category_detail_container, fragment).commit();
        if (findViewById(R.id.startUpPicture)!=null){
            ImageView IV_StartUp = 
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.startUpPicture);
            IV_StartUp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CategoryDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(CategoryDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode){
    case 0:
        onItemSelected(data.getIntExtra("CAT_ID", -1));
        break;
    case 1:
        SQLCategories _sql = new SQLCategories(CategoryListActivity.this);
        ArrayList<Categories> _categories =_sql.getAllCategories();
        _CLFragment.getListView().setAdapter(new CategoriesAdapter(CategoryListActivity.this, _categories));
        onItemSelected(-1);
        break;
    default:
        if(resultCode==1){
            onItemSelected(data.getIntExtra("CAT_ID", -1));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing each time with a new fragment why don't you update the data? I mean to have the `CategoryDetailFragment` inside from the very beginning (from XML layout or from `onCreate`) and perform only an update on its fields by passing the content data (the `ContentDetail` object) and update the viewss inside.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but I encountered another issue, during the same time I cannot pull any data from the database. A query that should have returned 3 rows returned 0. Afterwards, when all is loaded again, I launch the same function and it pulls the 3 rows that I needed.